# PHP code alternative to cron

Tags: php, email, cron

I found some php code that was "an alternative to cron" I'm a total noob to PHP, so would this code work in my situtation? Her's the snippet:

```
<?php

if (($last + $interval) >= time()) {
// execute some script(s)
}

?>
```

I'm trying to delay a script to send emails. Here's the email script:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{

 $headers = "From: Memory Jet <your_company@example.com>\r\n";


$to_visitor = $_POST["email"];
$common_data = $_POST["message"];
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $common_data, $headers);

} ?>
```

Comment: i don't see how you can call that an alternative to cron. How about explaining what your trying to achieve. For a simple delay you can just use sleep()

Comment: No, it wouldn't work (alone), but I guess, that this is not your real question.

Comment: This would be a big delay so sleep wouldn't work.

Comment: you could explain the issue a lot better; then you would get better answers.

Comment: Your right, I'm sorry. I want to send this email at a specific time to be determined by that code. How could I get it so that this email would be sent within a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the code you provided, you will need to insert the entire second code snippet (minus the  tags) into the part in the first where it says: // execute some script(s). You will also need to define the variables $time and $interval

Having said that, I agree with the other posters that this is not an actual alternative to cron. Cron is the *nix version of what you might know as scheduled tasks in Windows. Basically you write a script and use cron to schedule it (without later human intervention). On the other hand, the "alternative" provided in your post only works when you (or something else) run the PHP script manually (by accessing it through the Internet, for example).

Answer (score 2):

The PHP "Alternative" to cron, save it as a script on your host and execute it once. It will call itself each second once, if the internal processing takes longer, it will take longer as well, so fork your tasks in the background so that they don't hinder the script too long from executing:

```
<?php
header("X-PHP-CRON-STATUS: failure.");
isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) || die('failure.');
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
header("Content-Length: 8");
header("Connection: close");
header("X-PHP-CRON-STATUS: started.", 1);
echo 'started.';
flush();

/* run cron jobs in background / HTTP "background" script like this one */


$each = 1; /* second(s) */
$sofar = microtime(1) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
if (0 < ($wait = $each - $sofar))
{
    usleep($wait * 1000000);
}

$uri = 'http' . ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
!$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80" && $uri .= ':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
$uri .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
file_get_contents($uri);
```

Scripts like this are very fragile, so better get a real cron, it's worth. For tinkering, it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Cron would be used to, for example, send an email at a specific time every day. To do this you could write a script of some kind outside of your PHP app and actually use CRON to schedule it.

Here's a site with a couple of methods you could use to do this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/